# Force browser to use CSS 2.1

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, visualforce

Is there a browser/extension/method which forces the browser to use Cascading Style Sheets Level 2 Revision 1 (CSS 2.1) Specification for testing purpose?

I'm working on Visualforce page and it works fine when rendered as HTML page. But when rendering as PDF, the page is garbled.

On debugging the CSS with https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator, no issue is reported with CSS 2.1 spec.

Visual force PDF renderer uses Flying Saucer which is limited to CSS 2.1.

Need to render the page with CSS 2.1 specification to debug.

Comment: Use only ccs2.1

Comment: simply download an old version of the browser and run it inside an old OS